# issue with ansible fetch module

Tags: ansible

I am using the below Ansible code to get the file system details (`NAME,MOUNTPOINT,FSTYPE,SIZE`) from node servers to control server. I am not getting any issues while running the playbook. But the CSV file is not copied to control machine.

Can anyone please help me on this?

```yaml
  tasks:
    - name: Fsdetails
      shell: |
        lsblk -o NAME,MOUNTPOINT,FSTYPE,SIZE > $(hostname).csv
      register: fsdetails_files_to_copy

    - name: Fetch the fsdetails
      fetch:
         src: "{{ item }}"
         dest: /data3/deployments/remediation
         flat: yes
      with_items: "{{ fsdetails_files_to_copy.stdout_lines }}"
```

Output:

```
PLAY [all] ************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ************************************************************************************
ok: [10.xxx.xxx.xx]

TASK [Fsdetails] ******************************************************************************************
changed: [10.xxx.xxx.xx]

TASK [Fetch the fsdetails] ********************************************************************************

PLAY RECAP ************************************************************************************************
10.xxx.xxx.xx              : ok=2    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `shell` command is not returning anything, since it is writing the output to the CSV file. Because of this, your `fetch` task has nothing to loop on (`stdout_lines` is an empty list).

What you could do is make your shell task `echo` the CSV name `$(hostname)`:

```yaml
- name: Fsdetails
  shell: |
    lsblk -o NAME,MOUNTPOINT,FSTYPE,SIZE > $(hostname).csv && echo $(hostname).csv
  register: fsdetails_files_to_copy
```

This way, your `fetch` task will pick the correct filename to download.